# How to embed if statement inside a map

Tags: scala, if-statement, apache-spark

I have a definition calculation cosine similarity for each combination coming from a matrix. However, I want the definition runs under some certain conditions.

The definition is given below:

```
def neighbours(signatures: Iterable[Signature], minCosineSimilarity: Double): Iterator[MatrixEntry] = {
   signatures.
      toSeq.
      sortBy(_.index). // sort in order to create an upper triangular matrix
      combinations(2)
      .map {
        case first :: other :: nil =>
        if((first.index < 4 && other.index > 3) || (first.index > 3 && other.index < 4)){}
        val cosine = Cosine(first.vector, other.vector)
        MatrixEntry(first.index, other.index, cosine)
    }.
      filter(_.value >= minCosineSimilarity)
  }
```

It calculates cosine similarity for a given pair coming from "combinations(2)" line. I have added a line containing if statement. How can I make this if condition valid here?

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking here.  Does this code not compile for you or does it not do something that you want it to do?  Be clear about what the issue is so you can get more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `collect` instead of `map`. You can then use an `if guard`:

```
  .collect {
    case first :: other :: nil if (first.index < 4 && other.index > 3) || (first.index > 3 && other.index < 4) =>
    val cosine = Cosine(first.vector, other.vector)
    MatrixEntry(first.index, other.index, cosine)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is MatrixEntity to only get computed if that if statement you wrote is true. If that's the case then this should work...

```
def neighbours(signatures: Iterable[Signature], minCosineSimilarity: Double): Iterator[MatrixEntry] = {
  signatures.
  toSeq.
  sortBy(_.index). // sort in order to create an upper triangular matrix
  combinations(2)
  .map {
    case first :: other :: nil =>
    if((first.index < 4 && other.index > 3) || (first.index > 3 && other.index < 4)){
        val cosine = Cosine(first.vector, other.vector)
        Some(MatrixEntry(first.index, other.index, cosine))
    }else{None} 
  }.filter{ 
    _.exists{_.value >= minCosineSimilarity}
    }.map{_.get}
}
```